# Rails/SQL: How to order grouped records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a tabel called `SessionHistory` with the column of `ip`.

I now want to first group the records having the same `ip` and then sort the groups by the number of records in each group.

For Example:

```
Record1: ip = 3
Record2: ip = 1
Record3: ip = 2
Record4: ip = 1
Record5: ip = 2
Record6: ip = 1
```

grouped ...

```
Group1:
    Record1: ip = 3
Group2:
    Record2: ip = 1
    Record4: ip = 1
    Record6: ip = 1
Group3:
    Record3: ip = 2
    Record5: ip = 2
```

sorted ...

```
Group1:
    Record2: ip = 1
    Record4: ip = 1
    Record6: ip = 1
Group2:
    Record3: ip = 2
    Record5: ip = 2
Group3:
    Record1: ip = 3
```

**My Approach:**

```
        - @devices = SessionHistory.all.group_by(&:ip)
        - @devices.keys.sort.each do |ip| # not sorted after size of group!
            %h1= ip
            %h4= @devices[ip].first.name # somehow not giving anything!
            - @devices[ip].each do |session|
                %h1.tiny= session.name
```

There are some problems though, the groups are obviously not sorted after their size and I am not able to read values from single records in one group.

Comment: if you can implement the requirement in plain sql, you can use the ActiveRecord::Base.connnection to execute the sql directly.

Comment: @nickcen I don't know a way to write this with plain sql

Comment: So i don't think this a problem directly relative to Rails, but more relative to sql.

Comment: @nickcen So I edited the title and tags of the post ... but I still think it's possible to achieve this with just Rails and Ruby -> I edited the post to show my approach to this.

Comment: Yeah, its is very possible to achieve it with just rails.

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter and how? ;)

Comment: `SessionHistory.group(:ip).count` This gives a mapping of the `row id` and the number of records in them. The `row id` become the key, the number of records is the value  @jonhue

Answer (score 0):

Grouped SQL queries are returned as a Hash, where the keys are the values of IPs which records are grouped by and the values are the objects themselves. To sort that kind of results you could use the `.sort` method to order by hash values count:

```
@devices = SessionHistory.all.group_by(&:ip)
@devices.sort!{|a,b| b.values.count <=> a.values.count }
```

Or reverse ordering as simple as calling `.reverse`

```
@devices = SessionHistory.all.group_by(&:ip)
@devices.sort!{|a,b| b.values.count <=> a.values.count }.reverse!
```

Not an SQL solution, but at least it is clean and just works™

Comment: What would I need to take instead of `values` or what does it represent?

Comment: Values represent the records that are grouped under the given key on the hash returned by the `group_by` method.

Comment: `.values` in this case will be SessionHistory instances

Comment: hmm... I get `undefined method 'values'`. Also I get an array instead of a hash: `#<Array:0xb7d7dc0>`

Comment: Maybe you are using http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group instead of http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by it should be the latter

Comment: I am using `.group_by(&:ip)`

Comment: Well, according to this http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by#820-returns-an-ActiveSupport-OrderedHash expected return is ActiveSupport::OrderedHash, if Array is being returned, maybe you have some vendor code or an instance method overriding default behavior.